# Fluent NHibernate: do not generate any mapping for class during SchemaExport

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I've got an application talking to two databases, and it runs fine, and my tests pass, except when it tries to export the current DB schema, it outputs everything for both DBs in one block, and when it tries to validate the object model / DB schema line up, it tries to look in one database for everything, when one class (which is external data, hence the foreign DB) should not be mapped. I provided a mapping override for the class so that NH can correctly load/use data from the foreign DB (it's read-only), but now when I export my schema, it tries to make that table.

I tried `IgnoreBase(typeof(Unit))` but this has no effect (whereas `IgnoreBase(typeof(Entity))` does work correctly). I have decorated the custom repository methods with `[SessionFactory(DataGlobals.FOREIGN_DB_FACTORY_KEY)]` where that simply defines a constant string to use as a key for the `SessionFactory`, but I'm sure if there's something I need to decorate the class (`Unit`) with or pass a different parameter to `SchemaExport` ...

```
public void CanGenerateDatabaseSchema(){ 
var session = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().OpenSession();

        using (TextWriter stringWriter = new StreamWriter("../../../../db/schema/UnitTestGeneratedSchema.sql"))
        {
            new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(true, false, false, session.Connection, stringWriter);
        }
}

public void CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings()
    {
        var allClassMetadata = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().GetAllClassMetadata();

        foreach (var entry in allClassMetadata)
        {
            NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria(entry.Value.GetMappedClass(EntityMode.Poco))
                 .SetMaxResults(0).List();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Fluent NHibernate you can use `SchemaAction.None` to disable the generation of the schema for a particular table.

#### Example:

```
public class BankInfoMap : ClassMap<BankInfo>
{
    public BankInfoMap()
    {
        Schema(“viplookups.dbo”);
        Table(“bnkroute”);
        SchemaAction.None();

        Id(x => x.Id).Column(“bnkrouteid”);
        Map(x => x.AbaNumber).Column(“crouting”);
        Map(x => x.Name).Column(“ccompname”);
        Map(x => x.City).Column(“ccity”);
        Map(x => x.State).Column(“cstate”);
        Map(x => x.PhoneNumber).Column(“cphone1″);
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://lostechies.com/rodpaddock/2010/06/29/using-fluent-nhibernate-with-legacy-databases/

Comment: That seems to **mostly** work, but it still generates a relationship table (this class has a parent-child relationship stored in another table, referenced explicitly in code via `HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildUnits).AsSet().Cascade.None().Table("xyz").Schema("abc").Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Subselect().ParentKeyColumn(...).ChildKeyColumn(...).BatchSize(1000).Where(...).OrderBy(...);` 

The SchemaExport still tries to create table ABC.XYZ

Comment: Did you add the `SchemaAction.None()` in the `ChildUnits` mapping?

Comment: ChildUnits are the same entity type (`Unit`). They by definition use the same mapping file.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?  This could be a bug.

Comment: I know that they've made some changes in v3.2 that may have fixed this but what you're experiencing seems like a bug to me.  If it still happens in the latest version I would submit a bug report to the [JIRA](https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) or look if one already exists for this problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug then, since updating to 3.2 doesn't change anything. Before reporting via JIRA, is this really NH's problem or Fluent's problem... seems like the latter, and they don't have a public bug tracker that I see. I'll try their mailing list / google group.

Comment: To me this is a bug in NHibernate.  Take a look at this: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/12/15/customizing-schema-export-with-schema-action.aspx  It seems like if you specify schema-action=none on the class it should also disable the schema generation for any many to many tables defined within that class.  Maybe you can post a question about this in the nhusers group on google groups.